# VS 2010: Max line length guide does not render

Tags: visual-studio-2010, formatting

In VS 2008, we were able to add a max line length guide ref: http://blog.feradz.com/2009/02/add-line-length-marker-in-visual-studio/

However when we attempt to do the same thing in VS 2010, it does not work. Does anyone know how to achieve this in VS 2010?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The guidelines are *not supported* in VS 2010 natively (I Assume as part of the WPF rewrite of the editor this hidden functionality was not maintained).

But you can add them back with an extension <s>(or at least in the beta/RC you could)</s>: [Editor Guidelines UI – Extension #4](http://blogs.msdn.com/saraford/archive/2010/04/05/editor-guidelines-ui-extension-4.aspx) .

**Update**: I now have this working in Ultimate Edition RTM, by adding the extension from Tools | Extensions and searching online for "text guideline".